# Python, can't use same port after calling socket.close()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I wrote the following code in python which get's a device ip address and a ports and hosts html webpage on it:

import socket

```
def get_user_input(port=80):
    ip = wifiCfg.wlan_sta.ifconfig()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((ip[0], port))
    s.listen(5)

    while 1:
        input_var = None
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        request = conn.recv(1024)
        request = urlDecode(str(request))
        parsed_url = urlparse(extract_string(request, 'GET '))
        requested_path = parsed_url.path
        if requested_path == '/submit':
            input_var = '123' # Simpler version of my code with same logic
 
        conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
        conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
        conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
        conn.sendall(response)
        conn.close()
        
        if input_var:
            s.close()
            return input_var
```

If I know for sure that the user will visit `/submit` then why when I re-run my code I need to change the port to new one or my code won't run (Getting OS Error)

Comment: This is normal behavior: the port remains blocked for a period of time (2 minutes or so), so that any lingering packets for the original socket don't mistakenly get delivered to a new socket.  This is rather inconvenient, especially during development; it's not that big of a problem in the first place, and the blocking time period is *absurdly* long for modern networking hardware - so the usual practice is to turn off this "feature" via the `SO_REUSEADDR` flag on the socket.

Comment: This is addressed in the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example) for the `socket` module.